# VBA Code - Call a macro and stop the run until certain lines

Tags: vba

I have a Macro (the name is Test() ) from the Module1, and normally to call this Macro, i am using the code :

Call Module1.Test

But i am looking to a VBA code to call my Macro Test from Module1 until certain lines of code

Example stop the runing when the macro is arriving to the line 900

Thanks for your help

Comment: 900 lines is way too long for one macro. Break it up into smaller subroutines.

Comment: Then, place `Exit Sub` after that line... Do you want this "certain lines of code" to be variable? Why don't you edit your question and post a (dummy) piece of code to make the question reproductible? To make it exiting at the tenth code line, for instance... Then, please try explaining what you need accomplishing. I am sure that we can find/suggest a better approach. Exiting after a specific number of code lines cannot be a purpose by itself, I suppose...

Comment: Do you want to stop = pause your macro when reaching that line or do you want your macro to stop further execution of the following code, e.g. exit the macro when reaching that line? And @BigBen is right: 900 lines of code for a single macro is way too much. Do your future self a favor and break it down into smaller methods.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I would like to do that because the First part of my code is to centralize every databases and the second part of my code is to make costs allocation. the purpose of the module where i will call my macro is to run macro until before costs allocation. I could copy/paste the code but if i am making somes changes, i will have everytime to copy/paste code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I can guess that you might want to run the Test() subroutine in different parts:

```vb
Sub Test(Optional stop_at_900 = False)
    Debug.Print vbTab & "do the first part of the code"
    'other code
900: If stop_at_900 Then Exit Sub ' 900 label is not needed, it is placed here for labeling
    
    Debug.Print vbTab & "do the rest of the code"
    'other code
End Sub

Sub UsageExample()
    Debug.Print "Doing full Test() code..." ' usual (full) use
    Call Test
    
    Debug.Print "Doing Test() code until 900 line..."   '
    Call Test(stop_at_900:=True) 'partial use
End Sub
```